# Segmentation Fault using when while loop

Tags: c

I am writing a program which take a line from user and invert case of letters 
The following code works fine

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(void) {
    printf("Enter line: ");
    char *input_ptr;
    size_t input_length;
    ssize_t read = (int) getline(&input_ptr, (void *) (&input_length), stdin);
    if (read != -1) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < input_length; i++) {
            int c = *(input_ptr + i);
            if (isupper(c)) {
                printf("%c", tolower(c));
            } else {
                printf("%c", toupper(c));
            }
        }
    } else {
        puts("Something Wrong Happened ...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change the for loop to while loop:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(void) {
    printf("Enter line: ");
    char *input_ptr;
    size_t input_length;
    ssize_t read = (int) getline(&input_ptr, (void *) (&input_length), stdin);
    if (read != -1) {
        while (*input_ptr != '\0') {
            int c = *input_ptr;
            input_ptr++;
            if (isupper(c)) {
                printf("%c", tolower(c));
            } else {
                printf("%c", toupper(c));
            }
        }
    } else {
        puts("Something Wrong Happened ...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It says segmentation error after I have entered my line. 
May I know what happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `(void *) (&input_length)`  instead of `&input_length`? It's not that probnlem here, but it's useless and confusing.

Comment: The presence of the fishy cast `(int) getline(...` suggests that something isn't right. This cast should not be needed. Perhaps you have the compiler set to strict standard C and so the compiler won't find the prototype to `getline`. What happens when you remove this cast, compiler error?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry for the confusion, `(void *)` and `(int)` were not needed. They are presence because I was getting some other error and I was trying to fix it and I have forgotten to remove them

Comment: @Kallzvx actually `(void *)` is not needed and `(int)` is utterly wrong

Comment: @Kallzvx Ok, never use casts to resolve such problems, they tend to just hide the problem "under the carpet" without actually solving it. If you get some strange compiler error that you don't understand how to fix, you could just post the code + a copy of the compiler message here on SO. For example, a common cause for strange compiler errors that seem to be resolved with casts, is when compiling C code with a C++ compiler - in which case the proper solution is to use the right tool, not to change the code.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks! I was fixing the error in a bad way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialised `input_ptr` so the code has undefined behaviour. You might have passed an invalid buffer address to `getline`. You should also initialise `input_length`, so

```
char *input_ptr = NULL;
size_t input_length = 0;
```

The function [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) expects either a pointer to memory you allocated yourself, or `NULL` to indicate that the function should allocate memory.

> If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set `0` before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line. This buffer should be freed by the user program even if `getline()` failed.

Note, you should not increment a pointer which you intend to free later.